# elastic index mapping alias shows up empty in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have lots of indices in elastic with similar mapping. they all have an alias Log which points to the main text field I like to show as log.
(elasic-stack v6.5.0)

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "unitylog": {
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
        },
:
        "Message": {
          "type": "text"
        },
:
        "log": {
          "type": "alias",
          "path": "Message"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Another index have this alias:

```
    "log": {
      "type": "alias",
      "path": "ProxyLog"
    }
```

If I go into kibana and combine all different indices it says Log is empty, I can take Message and ProxyLog as separate columns. How can I use only log.

Comment: Do you see the `log` field in your index pattern? If not you might need to refresh the existing index pattern that maps to your different indexes

Comment: log is in index pattern, but Kibana says it is empty